How to pass a Django form response through another template
I am creating a site for users to record their chicken's weights and I am trying to design a confirmation form for if a user tries to submit another weight for the same chicken on the same day. In other words, if a record already exists for that date, how to ask the user if it should be overwritten without the user re-entering the weight.
This is all I have so far:
# views.py
def add_record(request, chicken) -> HttpResponseRedirect | HttpResponsePermanentRedirect | HttpResponse:
    """
    View for the "record_weight.html" 
    Post & Get methods
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            record = form.save(commit=False)
            record.chicken = Chicken.objects.filter(number=chicken).first()
            record.date = datetime.now().date()
            try:
                Record.save(record)
            except ValidationError:
                # There is a record for that day, render another form asking if they want to overwrite
                return render(request, "tags/duplicate_record.html", {"bird": record.chicken}) 
            return redirect("/admin/tags/record/") 

    form = RecordForm()
    try:
        birds = Chicken.objects.all()

        req_bird = birds.filter(number=chicken).first()
    except Chicken.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Bird does not exist")
    try:
        req_records = Record.objects.filter(chicken_id=chicken).order_by("date").reverse()
    except Record.DoesNotExist:
        req_records = []
    return render(request, "tags/record_weight.html", {"bird": req_bird, "records": req_records, "form": form, "nav_filter": get_birds_navbar(birds)})

# duplicate_records.html (styling removed for easier reading)

{% extends "tags/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>There is already a weight for today!</h2>
        <p>Do you want to overwrite that entry</p>
        <form>
            <a href="/records/{{ bird.number }}">No</a>
            <button>Overwrite</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

I frankly cannot find any way to implement this functionality.
Thanks in advance!

If you want to do that without redirecting to another view, you can use form errors to check with user if they need data to be overwritten, and different names of template buttons to confirm the choice. This is simplified view (without validations etc.):
def add_record(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecordForm(request.POST)
        overwrite = True if 'do_overwrite' in request.POST else False
        keep = True if 'keep' in request.POST else False
        date = form.data['date']
        if Record.objects.filter(date=date):
            if overwrite:
                # Overwrite the record as you see fit
                pass
            elif keep:
                # Redirect to somewhere else
                pass
            else:
                form.add_error('date', 'Do you want to overwrite that entry?')
                context['ask_overwrite'] = True
        else:
            # Save the record
            pass
    else:
        form = RecordForm()
    context['form'] = form    
    
    return render(request, 'tags/record_weight.html', context=context)

And this is template with different buttons:
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.date}}
    {% if form.date.errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.date.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% if ask_overwrite %}
        <button type="submit" name="do_overwrite">Overwrite</button>
        <button type="submit" name="keep">No</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>


In your existing approach, you can create another view and process override in that function, finally redirect to your main page.
Implementation steps:

create another view let say override_record and process the confirmation in that function.

once done redirect to record page.


Sample Code
in views.py
def override_record(request, chicken):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # your override code
        pass
        
    return redirect("/admin/tags/record/")

in duplicate_records.htm
{% extends 'tags/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>There is already a weight for today!</h2>
      <p>Do you want to overwrite that entry</p>
      <form action="{% url  'override_record' %}">
        <a href="/records/{{ bird.number }}">No</a>
        <button>Overwrite</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

Better approach would be show the confirmation popup to user on same page, on user confirmation, process the override request.
